# Numerically estimating expected value of f(x) when x is normally distributed

Tags: numerics, integration

I need to estimate
$$
\mathbb{E}_x[f_i(x)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f_i(x) p(x) dx
$$
for many functions $f_i(x)$, where $p(x)$ is the density of a normal distribution. The evaluation of all the functions $f_i(x)$ is expensive.
I was looking into Bayesian Quadrature but I cannot find an (approximately) optimal way of choosing sample points.

Comment: How accurate does this estimate need to be? Highly accurate or somewhat accurate? Also: what properties about $f$ do you know? Is it $L$-Lipschitz or smooth in some other sense, or does $f$ vary widely?

Comment: The approximation doesn't need to be higly accurate, $f$ is L-Lipschitz.

Comment: in that case, you can always get a Monte-Carlo estimate (depending on your internal definition of “highly accurate.”) Since $f$ is Lipschitz, $f(x)$ is sub-Gaussian and obeys nice concentration properties.

Comment: The problem is that Monte-Carlo converges slowly. I was looking to find a way of defining the sampling points (with the corresponding weights) to converge faster than Monte-Carlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the answers to [this question on CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/434669/244807). There you can find a worked out solution (including R-code) based on Gauss-Hermite quadrature, which is especially designed for this problem (note that it requires a variable transformation) and -in a different answer- a comparsion of MonteCarlo (slow) with the R builtin function *integrate* (fast).