# 2-dimensional Gauss-Hermite quadrature in R

Tags: numerics, integration, r

A similar question was asked [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/33269/numerically-estimating-expected-value-of-fx-when-x-is-normally-distributed/33767#33767) and the given answer is perfect for a unidimensional integration.

**I need to make bidimensional integration in R with a Gauss-Hermite quadrature:**
$$\int_{R^2} h(p1,p2) \phi(p1,p2) dp1 dp2$$
with $p1$ and $p2$ two parameters that follow a multivariate normal distribution of density $\phi(.)$ such as:
$$p1,p2 \sim \mathcal{N_2} (\mu, \Sigma) $$
with $\mu = \left(\matrix{0\\ 1} \right)$ and $\Sigma = \left[\matrix{0.6&0.5\\0.5&0.25} \right]$.

I tried some packages in `R` but the results I got were very different from one another. I also tried the solution [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/notes-on-multivariate-gaussian-quadrature-with-r-code/) but I'm not sure of the results I got.

I am looking for a simple solution, preferably based on `gauss.quad`.

Not being an expert, I have no idea of when to divide by $\pi$, if I should make a rescaling in my case and so on.

Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Where does the **gauss.quad** function come from? And what is **h**?